# How to get the median of a 2d Arraylist

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the median of an `ArrayList` that has 110 elements. Every 5 elements is a node and I want the median of the nodes. I have tried this code but it's throwing an out of bound error. Any suggestions?

```java
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    double Median = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++)
    {
        Median = ((list[i-1][j]/2) + (list[i-1][j]/2)-1)/2;
    }
    System.out.println(Median);
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: What is your definition of median because the median by most definitions is the middle of a sorted list of values.  And I don't see any mention of anything being sorted.

Comment: @Helper189 The format of the input data is unclear: are you dealing with a 1D list or a 2D list? Double access syntax is used (`list[i][j]`), but the size of only the outer list (`list.size()`) is used. Also, are you dealing with an array (i.e. `double[]`) or with a collection (i.e. `List<Double>`)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```java
static List<Double> findMediansOf(List<Double> nodes) {
    List<Double> medians = new ArrayList<>();

    // preventing out of bounds
    if (nodes.isEmpty()) {
        return medians;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i += 5) {
        List<Double> unsortedNode = nodes.subList(i, i + 5);

        // sorting `unsortedNode`
        List<Double> node = unsortedNode.stream()
            .sorted()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // node has always a size of 5, no need to average in case of an even element count
        medians.add(node.get(2));
    }

    return medians;
}
```

Now if you want to print the result, you just have to do:

```java
findMediansOf(nodes).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: That's not the median.  Its the middle.   And it also doesn't compile.

Comment: @WJS Thanks, I forgot java didn't accept basic datatypes (like `double`, `int`) as generic type arguments. It should be fixed now. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median), the median *is* the middle element, isn't it?

Comment: No, the median is the middle of a *sorted* list of elements,.  For example, the median income of a state says that there are just as many folks making less than the median as there are making more.  Having said that, I did ask the OP what they meant by median.

Comment: @WJS I had not understood the question properly, now I believe I'm answering it. The OP only needs the median of a list of 5 elements (which is an odd number, so no average needed).

Comment: Right.  Did you know about either `Collections.sort()` or `List.sort()`?  No need to use streams.

Comment: @WJS The problem with `Collections.sort(...)` is that it mutates the list in place, and I thought it would be more convenient to not modify the input data